# linux joournalctl read specified input file and not the local syslog

Tags: linux, syslog, journalctl

I know this is a long shot. Im missing something from the man pages I can find.

I've setup remote event /system logging to a log server (syslog-ng). That works fine.

It has its own log dir and each host creates its own log file marked with its ip ( below)

NOTE: I've found some examples which change the journalctl config or syslog-ng config. I think that would mess up the logging. Its fine for a system change but not just running some scripts to look at data.

They are in :

/var/log/remote :

remote_syslog_192.168.0.163.log  remote_syslog_192.168.0.223.log
remote_syslog_192.168.0.17.log   remote_syslog_192.168.0.3.log
remote_syslog_192.168.0.18.log
remote_syslog_192.168.0.200.log

That is all good.
i.e :

Feb 23 09:54:41 192.168.0.4 smartd[840]: Device: /dev/sdc [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 64 to 65

ip 192.168.0.4 is the local pc Im running journalctl on and also the log server.

Now I need to process them.

journalctl seems a good option I can write scripts to pull out  records of interest.

i.e

journalctl -o json-pretty -u smartd

All good

Now for the bit Im missing

journalctl reads /var/log/syslog

I cant find a way to tell it to use a different log file.

I tried the -D/var/log/remote option  and the --root and the --file.
But it only ever reads /var/log/syslog - which is the local pc not the data sent from the remote ones.

Would someone please give me some pointers as journalctl looks perfect at extracting data from log files and its a lot easier than the other options I can think of such as awk or grep , cut etc etc.

Thank you for any suggestions you may have on a good way to pull records out of a syslog file.

Comment: I see a  --file option...

Comment: Btw, the way your are going, with multiple systems, remote viewing and so on, will result, when it gets really big, in a domain wide logging system. It might save you some time in the long run to look into the future, and start digging into systems like splunk and elastic search, graylog and logstash. Good luck.

Comment: Nope, `journalctl` does not use classic ASCII logs like `/var/log/syslog` at all. It uses binary-formatted, indexed journal files located in `/var/log/journal/*` and/or `/run/log/journal/` (the latter is non-persistent as it's on `tmpfs`). Usually `systemd-journald` gets all local log messages first, and forwards them to `syslogd` if one exists.

Comment: Hi Thank You for your replies, sorry I accidentally missed out of my question, I have tried --file --root & --directory.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about journalctl using the /var/og/journal. 
Ive never really used it before for much more than when a service fails to start.
It just looked as through it could would be a nice easy way to look at the logs from each system all in one place.
I'll take a  more deailed look into syslog-ng I dont know what that sends.
Actually, I never done anything like this before.  Hence why Im getting so easily lost.
Still even though Ive retired and only help out some local charity / communiity  groups its fun to keep a hand in. Thanks